# Active directory change first name size limit

Tags: active-directory, user-input

I want to change the maxmium length allowed for first name to 5, how do I do it?
I understand I can write more than it but when I press next/ok it should say error or something like that.

Does somebody know how?

I have a clue I need to use advanced settings..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Definition of every attributes in AD are set by the AD schema. Not sure if you can do (change) it but for sure, you shouldn't do it because of the consequences...